# Seems like ViewModel persists after its View is destroyed in extjs

Tags: extjs, mvvm, extjs6

I'm sure there's something I'm missing here and I just can't see what it is.

I have demo project I'm building in extjs 6. In it I have a grid of inventory items.

```
Ext.define("InventoryDemo.view.inventory.list.Inventory",{
    extend: "Ext.container.Container",
    xtype: 'inventory',

    requires: [
        "InventoryDemo.view.inventory.list.InventoryController",
        "InventoryDemo.view.inventory.list.InventoryModel"
    ],

    controller: "inventory-inventory",
    viewModel: {
        type: "inventory-inventory"
    },
    closable: true,

    listeners:{
        refreshList: 'onRefreshList'
    },


    layout:{
        type: 'hbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },
    items:[
        {
            xtype: 'grid',
            flex: 1,

            tbar:[
                {xtype: 'button', text: 'New Item', handler: 'newInventoryItem'}
            ],

            bind:{
                store: '{inventory}'
            },

            listeners:{
                itemclick: 'showDetails'
            },

            columns:[
                { text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name', flex: 1 },
                { text: 'Price', dataIndex: 'price' },
                { text: 'Active', dataIndex: 'active' },
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

When you click on a row, a new detail panel is created and the selected record is linked to its viewmodel and it's added to the container view that holds the grid. I also want to use the same detail panel when creating a new inventory record so I extracted the shared logic for creating and editing so it can be reused in the controller.

Here's the list's controller:

```
Ext.define('InventoryDemo.view.inventory.list.InventoryController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.inventory-inventory',

    config:{
        // holds the newly created detail panel
        detailsPanel: null
    },

    showDetails: function (grid, record, item, index, e, eOpts){
        this.createDetailsPanel();
        this.addTitleToDetailsPanel(record.get('name'));

        // This creates the link in the new detail panel's viewmodel for the
        // selected record. We specifically do NOT do this in the
        // `newInventoryItem`.
        details.getViewModel().linkTo('inventoryitem', record);

        this.addDetailsPanelToView();
    },

    newInventoryItem: function (button, e){
        this.createDetailsPanel();
        this.addTitleToDetailsPanel('New Item');

        // I thought that because the previous panel was destroyed during the
        // `createDetailsPanel` method any previously linked record would not
        // be linked to the new detail panel created and that not linking here
        // would give me an empty detail panel.
        this.addDetailsPanelToView();
    },


    createDetailsPanel: function (){
        if(this.getDetailsPanel() !== null){
            // I'm destroying any previous view here which, as I understand, 
            // would also destroy the the associated ViewController and ViewModel
            // which would also kill any links to the viewmodel
            this.getDetailsPanel().destroy();
        }

        details = Ext.create('InventoryDemo.view.inventory.details.Inventory',{
            session: true,
            listeners:{
                refreshList: 'onRefreshList'
            }
        });
        this.setDetailsPanel(details);
    },

    addDetailsPanelToView: function (){
        this.getView().add(this.getDetailsPanel());
    },

    addTitleToDetailsPanel: function (title){
        this.getDetailsPanel().setTitle("<h3>" + title + "</h3>");
    },

    onRefreshList: function (){
        this.getViewModel().get('inventory').load();
    }
});
```

The details panel being created looks like this:

```
Ext.define("InventoryDemo.view.inventory.details.Inventory",{
    extend: "Ext.form.Panel",

    requires: [
        "InventoryDemo.view.inventory.details.InventoryController",
        "InventoryDemo.view.inventory.details.InventoryModel"
    ],

    controller: "inventory-details-inventory",
    viewModel: {
        type: "inventory-details-inventory"
    },

    flex: 1,
    closable: true,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    reference: 'inventorydetails',
    defaults:{
        layout: 'anchor',
        anchor: '50%'
    },
    dockedItems:[
        {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            dock: 'bottom',
            ui: 'footer',
            items:[
                {xtype: 'button', text: 'Update', handler: 'updateRecord'},
                {xtype: 'button', text: 'Delete', handler: 'deleteRecord'}
            ]
        }
    ],

    items:[
        {
            xtype: 'hiddenfield',
            name: '_method',
            value: 'PUT'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: 'IDs',
            collapsible: true,
            defaults:{
                xtype: 'textfield'
            },
            items:[
                {
                    name: 'id',
                    fieldLabel: 'ID',
                    readOnly: true,
                    bind: '{inventoryitem.id}'
                },
                {
                    name: 'brand_id',
                    fieldLabel: 'Brand ID',
                    readOnly: true,
                    bind: '{inventoryitem.brand_id}'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: 'Details',
            defaults:{
                xtype: 'textfield'
            },
            items:[
                {
                    name: 'name',
                    fieldLabel: 'Name',
                    bind: '{inventoryitem.name}'
                },
                {
                    name: 'price',
                    fieldLabel: 'Price',
                    bind: '{inventoryitem.price}'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]

});
```

The problem that I'm running into is if I click on a row to view it's details (which works) and then click on the `New Item` button, the record that was loaded on the previous detail panel is still loaded on the new detail panel.

If I click the `New Item` button first I get the blank form I'm going for and if I select different item rows each of the records from the selected row loads into the detail panel correctly (it's not a situation where the record from the first row is "stuck" in the detail panel), but as soon as I select a row, the `New Item` button will only give me forms with the previously loaded record.

Is there something that would make a link to a viewmodel persist between the destruction and creation of two separate views/viewmodels/viewcontrollers (or is there a flaw in my controller logic that I'm just not seeing)?

Answer (score 0):

if the only thing you need in the detail's viewModel is this singular property you are trying to link to, consider not using a stand-alone viewModel for the detail at all.

When your detail panel resides in the items of your `inventory` view, it actually has natural access to the view's viewModel (`detailPanel.lookupViewModel()` will return the single closest viewModel in the component tree hierarchy). Bindings should work too.

However, if you need a separate viewModel for the detail panel, you can create the detail view with an ad-hoc `viewModel` config that gets merged into the detail's viewModel upon instantiation.

The view:

```
Ext.define('APP.view.TheView',{
    extend: "Ext.container.Container",
    alias: 'widget.theView',

    controller: 'theView',
    viewModel: { type: 'theView' },

    config: {
        detailConfig: { xtype: 'theDetail', reference: 'detail' }
    },

    items: ...
};
```

The view's viewController:

```
Ext.define('APP.controller.TheView',{
    extend: "Ext.app.ViewController",
    alias: 'controller.theView',

    onOpenDetail: function(){

        var detail = this.lookupReference('detail');

        if(!detail){

            var view = this.getView(),
                detailConfig = view.getDetailConfig(),
                theProperty = this.getViewModel().get('theProperty');

            detailConfig = Ext.apply({
                viewModel: {
                    // This actually gets correctly merged with whatever there is
                    // in the viewModel configuration of the detail
                    data: { theProperty: theProperty }
                }
            }, detailConfig));

            detail = view.add(detailConfig);
        }

        // Do something with the detail instance
    }
};
```

And the detail:

```
Ext.define('APP.view.TheDetail',{
    extend: "Ext.panel.Panel",
    alias: 'widget.theDetail',

    controller: 'theDetail',
    viewModel: { type: 'theDetail' },

    items: ...
};
```

Hope this helps a little! :-)